# Windows doesn't detect HDD and SSD, but Disk Manager does

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, boot, ssd

Windows doesn't detect two of my drives, after I installed a new one. I exchanged my previous SSD (old Patriot Inferno, 60gb) which had Windows 8.1 on it for a new OCZ ARC 100. However, after I installed a new system Windows does not recognize my old drives (both the HDD and SSD). Disk Management however does:

[image]

When I start Disk Management it asks me to Initialize Disk 0, but when I try to it also fails. What could be the problem?

Last week my Windows 8.1 computer suddenly stopped working. When turning it on, it would quickly flash a blue screen of death and restart. It appeared there was anHDD problem. I tried the automatic repairs from Windows Startup Repair, but it said it failed to repair the problem. I thought it was simply due to my old SSD, which I was going to exchange anyway, so I didn't think much about it.

Comment: Try ti initialize disk0 fron disk management or with Partition Wizard. For disk1 it says 'D', but that does not look like a drive letter. See whether you can assign a real drive letter.

Comment: Thank you, I completly forgot about Partition Wizard. Strangely enough it simply didn't want to work with letter "D", but it worked when changed to E. It appears my HDD is dead :/ Any idea what could have caused 2 disks to go bad?

Comment: Were you by any chance using windows dynamic volumes on those drives?